# A question about the category of functors

Tags: category-theory

[image]

Here in the example, why are the the objects of $C^D$ exactly the morphisms $f : X(a)\to X(b)$ of $C$? I feel confused because by the definition it gives, the objects should be the functors from $D\to C$. And I don't know the meaning of $X(a)$.

Also what does the map $t$ mean? the morphism of $C^D$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The category $D$ here has two objects $a,b$ thus a functor $X:D\rightarrow C$ is defined by $X(a)$ and $X(b)$ and the image of the map $i:a\rightarrow b$ and this gives the morphism $X(i):X(a)\rightarrow X(b)$. Conversely, every morphism $f:U\rightarrow V$ of $C$ defines a functor $X:D\rightarrow C$ by $X(a)=U, X(b)=V$ and $X(i)=f$.